# Mac app to share screen region in meeting apps

Tags: meetup

I'm teaching to python programming some kids with google meet. Google meet does not allow share screen region, so I'm looking some app free/open source to share only screen region in callings.

I'm already test camtwist, but it does not output good quality and takes up the camera output. So just like meet allows share single app window, I'm looking for an app that allows watch through it.

Some idea?

Answer (score 4):

OP here

I just tried VLC and works awesome.
File > Open capture devices > Screen
setting up the screen region dimensions and clic on Open.
Prefences > Video > uncheck window decorators

Comment: How do you set a screen region on the Open capture devices? I'm on Windows and can't find it, maybe that's why.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very late with this reply and it's not exactly what you are asking for, but https://github.com/Stengo/DeskPad solves the same issue in a slightly different way.

Instead of sharing a specific region it creates a virtual monitor that lives inside of an application window. You can use and share it just like a real monitor :)

Hopefully this is helpful to you!